# Best Cassandra 1.2 driver for Python, Should I forget about CQL?

Tags: cassandra, pycassa

I'm looking for a good driver for python:

1) Pycassa. It doesn't support CQL, and they dont think to do it soon.

2) https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-dbapi2/.

I thought to use cassandra-dbapi2 but [here](http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/when-will-pycassa-support-cql) a guy says that "it doesn't support connection pooling load balance advance features". On the other hand I can use PyCassa but it doesn't support CQL. Should do I try Pycassa and forget about CQL on the client?

I don't care about losing ORM features, actually I think It could be even worse sometimes because its force your team to learn new things (new features on the ORM API which you are using) where as SQL is something that people know. Why learn a new language when you already know SQL/CQL? But It's just an opinion...

What do you think is the best option? Should I forget about CQL?

Comment: I'm not asking for an opinion,what I want to know if i should use CQL in cassandra or use cassandra whithout CQL. I've modify the title It was confusing

Comment: These types of questions are incredibly useful. I believe they should be welcomed on Stackoverflow.

Comment: @alasarr: You're looking for https://github.com/datastax/python-driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pycassa or CQL supported driver, both are client API's implementing the thrift interface, base API of cassandra, so basically which ever API you choose it will ought to have the same functionality. For every CQL implementation there is an alternative in pycassa but if  are really liking pycassa and you still want to mix CQL with it, then you can execute CQL statements through pycassa using the execute_cql thrift call. And you can also check  **[pcmanus / python-cql](https://github.com/pcmanus/python-cql)** written by one of the cassandra committer.

Comment: pcmanus / python-cql  is the same as cassandra-dbapi2, and it has the pooling issue. Is this so bad? (see the last post in the following forum) http://www.datastax.com/support-forums/topic/when-will-pycassa-support-cql

Comment: if so go with pycassa, and try executing CQL statements  using the execute_cql thrift call. In the mean time keep an eye on other API's too, they may come up with resolved pooling issue in their next versions.

Comment: Can Pycassa connect to a Cassandra 1.2 database?